# How to unregister a service worker when the PWA has been trashed

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

This might sound like a dumb question, but here's the problem. I am developing a PWA for a client and everything works fine : the service worker gets installed, as well as the app on the desktop.

I know how to uninstall both the app and the service worker programmatically.
But, for instance on an old Samsung tablet running Android 4.4, the app icon can be dragged to the trash on the desktop (like any shortcut) and then the app is uninstalled, but the service worker is still active and running (I can see it in DevTools).

Question : how to get rid of service workers after a PWA has been trashed that way ?
My concern is that end users of the app might delete it that way, and still have a service worker active on their mobile...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The process for a service worker will automatically stop running after a short period of idleness–somewhere between under a minute to maybe 5 minutes, depending on the browser and operating system.

If you have Chrome's DevTools open, then that will artificially keep the service worker process alive indefinitely, to aid in debugging. (It would be frustrating if you were trying to debug something related to the state of the service worker, and the service worker process stopped right in the middle.)

This only applies when you've got DevTools open, though, so you should have faith that it will stop on its own if you're not "looking" at it.